# Getting a different constructor on DexPathList$Element

Tags: android, dex

I'm trying to figure out why when I ask for constructors on dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element, I only see one for Element(File, File, DexFile) but I'm expecting: public Element(File file, ZipFile zipFile, DexFile dexFile) (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore-snapshot/+/ics-mr1/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexPathList.java)

```
Constructor<?>[] c = dexElementClass.getConstructors();
```

where dexElementClass is dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element

Does anybody know why I'm getting DexPathList$Element(File, FIle, DexPath)? Is it my API version? is it the build tools?

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't be using these dalvik classes.

It changed in 4.2.2

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.2.2_r1.1%5E2..android-4.2.2_r1.1/